# How to choose default choice field from a list

Tags: python, django

In a django model I need to set a default for a choice field but I don't get how to do the syntax part

This is the list

```
CHAT_STYLES = [
    ("orange", "orange"),
    ("purple", "purple"),
    ("aquamarine", "aquamarine"),
    ("aqua", "aqua"),
    ("beige", "beige"),
    ("yellow", "yellow"),
    ("green", "green"),
    ("blue", "blue")
]
```

I tried to do like this

```
chat_styles = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CHAT_STYLES, default=CHAT_STYLES."purple")
```

or

```
 chat_styles = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CHAT_STYLES, default=CHAT_STYLES["purple"])
```

but it didn't work

Comment: `CHAT_STYLES[1][1]`

Comment: but what if the second value changes?

Comment: If the values are expected to change, I suggest you to overwrite the implementation while saving the model object. But I don't think those values should change over time because you are in a way defining some sort of constraint for the field, you may add more values in future, but removing the existing values might be something you'd like to stay away from.

Comment: You can use [Enumeration types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) rather than using a list of choices. Also if the values are expected to change they probably should not be a choice field but rather a foreign key to another model which stores those choices.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a TextChoices model to name all your choices and then use a name from those choices to set a default in the related model. Here, the max length is set to 10 as the longest value to be inserted in the field (aquamarine) is 10 characters long.

```
class ChatStyleModel(models.TextChoices):
    orange = ("orange", "orange")
    purple = ("purple", "purple")
    aquamarine = ("aquamarine", "aquamarine")
    aqua = ("aqua", "aqua")
    beige = ("beige", "beige")  
    yellow = ("yellow", "yellow")
    green = ("green", "green")
    blue = ("blue", "blue")

class ChatModel(models.Model):
    chat_styles = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ChatStyleModel.choices, default=ChatStyleModel.purple)
```

Answer (score 0):

max length should be 10, because aquamarine is the biggest string and has 10 characters.

Try this:

```
chat_styles = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHAT_STYLES, default='purple')
```